# Is there a way to check within an array nested in a dict?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am not even sure if this is possible as I am new to python. Essentially I want to construct a dict for lookup purposes - this is my first stab at a data structure.

```
lookup = {
    1000000: {
        "Name":"Neutral grassland",
        "values":[6150166, 1000000, 1000283, 1000516, 1000524, 1000525, 1000526, 
                  1300000, 1300016, 1300017, 1300522, 1300527, 1310000, 1320000]
    }
}
```

I would like a method, a little like `get()` but where I can return the whole object of 100000 when a number is found within the values array.

Is this possible? Bonkers?

Comment: `if my_value in lookup[1000000]["values"]: do_something()`

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you were thinking?

```
def search(num, lookup):
    for inner in lookup:
        if num in inner["values"]:
            return inner

lookup = {
    1000000: {
        "Name":"Neutral grassland",
        "values":[6150166, 1000000, 1000283, 1000516, 1000524, 1000525, 1000526, 1300000, 1300016, 1300017, 1300522, 1300527, 1310000, 1320000]
    }
}
n = 6150166
search(n, lookup)
```

Comment: Don't use `dict`, `list`, `str`, etc. as variable names - you're shadowing the builtins.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def get(v):
    if v in lookup[1000000]["values"]:
        return lookup[1000000]
```

It's pretty specific to the `lookup` dictionary, but it can be modified to support others.